# String ou Cursor no PLSQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11c

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma procedure que executa um select, porem trabalho com um mapa de bits, onde utilizo condicionais para realizar um select especifico dependendo do bit que for passado como parâmetro para procedure. Neste cenário uso uma variável varchar para guardar a instrução select a ser executado, contudo pode acontecer de mais de bit estar ligado, sendo assim realizo uma concatenação com o operador UNION para unir outro selects em um só.

Minha pergunta é a seguinte, se usar um cursor para guardar os dados ao inves de usar strings concatenadas, poderia aumentar a performance da procedure ou seja trazer os resultados mais rápido do a logica atual?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você pode postar o código da procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não. O custo de criação de um cursor para o banco é bem maior que o tratamento das strings

Comment: Sabe dizer se existe uma outra forma de otimizar este cenário?

Comment: talvez se usar valores numéricos e tratá-lo com operações lógicas bitwise (BITAND, BITOR) possa acelerar o processo.

Comment: Isso já acontece, veja:

Comment: ah... agora clareou. Na pergunta parecia que vc usava strings para criar o mapa de bits. O problema é que o cursor é específico para a stored procedure, ou seja vc sempre terá que recriar os cursores quando iniciar a SP. O que dá no mesmo que enviar a query novamente, ou talvez ainda demore mais por causa do custo de criação do cursor.

Comment: Isso tu viu que vai concatenando as query e com o operador UNION vai unindo os selects, se todos os 7 bits que utilizo estiver ligado ele vai passar pelos 7 ifs e unindo os selects até fazer um select só. Por isso pensei no cursor, mas agora acho que no final pode ser mais custoso para o banco. Obrigado pela ajuda.